# Why is the length of the reduce method one

Tags: javascript, reduce

Why is the length of the reduce method one? Doesn't he have two parameters?
I try to output the length of reduce method in browser and node server. They both show one. What's the reason? Shouldn't they be two?

Comment: the second is optional - look at the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Polyfill) code

Answer (score -1):

**edited**

`Function.length` seems to return number of only needed arguments (which is mentioned as "typical number of arguments expected by the function" in ECMA)

I checked through other functions like `map` and `filter` and they behaved the same, returning `1` for `length` though they accepts optional arguments.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length
https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-instances-length

---

As it is said inthe MDN, reduce results in a single output value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

If you are mentioning about something else, it is better to provide example code.

Comment: you don't understand the question - OP is asking about the value of `length` proeprty of the function (a function has a length property - good to know)